# What's the meanig of "in scorn of"?

Tags: meaning

I know the word "scorn" means "a feeling and expression of contempt or disdain for someone or something" but I cannot understand the meaning of the phrase below:

> Take action in scorn of
>   deference

So, Could you please tell me what the meaning of the phrase is?

The main text is here:

> That night everyone stayed indoors. Mother was blending oils in the
>   kitchen. Dad was in the extension, which I had begun to jokingly call the
>   Chapel. He was lying on the crimson sofa, a Bible resting on his stomach,
>   while Kami and Richard played hymns on the piano. I sat with my laptop
>   on the love seat, near Dad, and listened to the music. I had just begun a
>   message to Drew when something struck the back door. The door burst
>   open, and Emily flew into the room.
>
> Her thin arms were wrapped around her body and she was shaking,
>   gasping for breath. She wore no coat, no shoes, nothing but jeans, an old
>   pair I’d left behind, and one of my worn T-shirts. Mother helped her to the
>   sofa, wrapping her in the nearest blanket. Emily bawled, and for several
>   minutes not even Mother could get her to say what had happened. Was
>   everyone all right? Where was Peter? He was fragile, half the size he
>   should have been, and he wore oxygen tubes because his lungs had never
>   fully developed. Had his tiny lungs collapsed, his breathing stopped?The story came out haltingly, between erratic sobs and the clattering of
>   teeth. From what I could tell, when Emily had gone to Stokes that
>   afternoon to buy groceries, she had returned home with the wrong crackers
>   for Peter. Shawn had exploded. “How can he grow if you can’t buy the right
>   food!” he had screamed, then he’d gathered her up and flung her from their
>   trailer, into a snowbank. She’d pounded on the door, begging to be let in,
>   then she’d run up the hillside to the house. I stared at her bare feet as she
>   said this. They were so red, they looked as if they’d been burned.My parents sat with Emily on the sofa, one on each side of her, patting
>   her shoulders and squeezing her hands. Richard paced a few feet behind
>   them. He seemed frustrated, anxious, as if he wanted to explode into action
>   and was only just being held in check.Kami was still seated at the piano. She was staring at the group huddled
>   on the couch, confused. She had not understood Emily. She did not
>   understand why Richard was pacing, or why he paused every few seconds
>   to glance at Dad, waiting for a word or gesture—any signal of what should
>   be done.
>
> I looked at Kami and felt a tightening in my chest. I resented her for
>   witnessing this. I imagined myself in Emily’s place, which was easy to do—I
>   couldn’t stop myself from doing it—and in a moment I was in a parking lot,
>   laughing my high-pitched cackle, trying to convince the world that my wrist
>   wasn’t breaking. Before I knew what I was doing I had crossed the room. I
>   grasped my brother’s arm and pulled him with me to the piano. Emily was
>   still sobbing, and I used her sobs to muffle my whispers. I told Kami that
>   what we were witnessing was private, and that Emily would be
>   embarrassed by it tomorrow. For Emily’s sake, I said, we should all go to
>   our rooms and leave it in Dad’s hands.
>
> Kami stood. She had decided to trust me. Richard hesitated, giving Dad a
>   long look, then he followed her from the room.I walked with them down the hallway then I doubled back. I sat at the
>   kitchen table and watched the clock. Five minutes passed, then ten. Come
>   on, Shawn, I chanted under my breath. Come now.
>   I’d convinced myself that if Shawn appeared in the next few minutes, it
>   would be to make sure Emily had made it to the house—that she hadn’t
>   slipped on the ice and broken a leg, wasn’t freezing to death in a field. But
>   he didn’t come.
>
> Twenty minutes later, when Emily finally stopped shaking, Dad picked
>   up the phone. “Come get your wife!” he shouted into it. Mother was
>   cradling Emily’s head against her shoulder. Dad returned to the sofa and
>   patted Emily’s arm. As I stared at the three of them huddling together, I
>   had the impression that all of this had happened before, and that
>   everyone’s part was well rehearsed. Even mine.It would be many years before I would understand what had happened
>   that night, and what my role in it had been. How I had opened my mouth
>   when I should have stayed silent, and shut it when I should have spoken
>   out. What was needed was a revolution, a reversal of the ancient, brittle
>   roles we’d been playing out since my childhood. What was needed—what
>   Emily needed—was a woman emancipated from pretense, a woman who
>   could show herself to be a man. Voice an opinion. **Take action in scorn of
>   deference**. A father.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Comment: It's essentially [a Victorian usage.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+scorn+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) It might be okay today in certain literary contexts (opinions may differ on that), but it's unlikely it would ever be suitable for a learner to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole ending of that paragraph is written in a poetic register, violating the rules of grammatical prose and even normal usage. There is no rule against trying to write in a poetic register except that others may find it obscure, pretentious, or both.

**The force that through the green fuse drives the flower drives my red blood** is meaningless if interpreted literally, but it is great poetry. Of course, few of us can match Dylan Thomas, who wrote the only decent villanelle in the English language, so, in my view, few of us should even try.

The meaning of that purple prose is **What was needed -- what Emily needed -- was a woman emancipated from the pretences of tradition, a woman as strong as any father imagined by tradition, a woman willing to scorn the dictates of traditional deference, willing to speak out and to act.**

Some can write like Dylan Thomas; most of us cannot. In my opinion, those of us who cannot should learn to write prose. As written, the quoted passage is facially absurd: at what time in the history of the world were women not able to speak. What is meant is that women would be punished, socially or physically, for doing certain things and so, quite rationally, were frequently unwilling to do them. The women who emancipated women were brave women who did what other women could have done but feared to do. **I wear my clothes, not men's clothes.**

EDIT: The quote about clothes (actually a slight mis-quote) is from the 19th century feminist doctor, Mary Edwards Walker, the only woman to have won the Cobgressional Medal of Honor, which was awarded for her work as a battlefield surgeon during the Civil War. I should have attributed it initially.

Comment: Ever heard of the suffragette movement when women were [imprisoned for voicing their dissent](https://mashable.com/2015/10/28/suffragettes-in-prison/?europe=true)? Ever heard of domestic violence, and battered wives? The narrator in the story was a victim of psychological and physical abuse. The man in that family scene, her father, did not act like a father who protects his children but as the stereotypical man who remains deaf to the sobs of his daughter and his wife as he considers women (in the story) to be the inferior sex.

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for a critical appraisal of the passage, that Dylan Thomas is a great poet and story teller is irrelevant to the question posed by the OP.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Had you ever heard of Mary Edwards Walker? And the fact remains:  the passage is written in a poetic register that is ineffective **as demonstrated by the OP needing to ask what it meant**. By the way, do you know any way to disagree that does not attribute ignorance or malice to others?

Comment: The OP is a nonnative speaker, their questions about the text has little to do with the author's prose.  She writes well. I'm pretty certain that @Peace would have greater difficulty tackling Dylan Thomas, Emily Dickenson, Wilfred Owen or Shelley.

Comment: In your opinion, she writes well. **A woman who could show herself to be a man** is pure nonsense: the speaker wants to be one of the pitiful creatures that men are? What is meant is that she wants women to be what men claim to be but are not. Simply incompetent writing.

Comment: The speaker is speaking figuratively, not literally. Mormon women, the father in the story is a fervent Mormon,  are expected to be submissive. [*"It's hard to describe how revolutionary it is for Mormon women to speak up," she recalled of the experience.*](https://www.ncronline.org/blogs/ncr-today/female-panelists-share-their-struggles-male-dominated-religions)

Comment: @Mari-Lou I get that the authot is speaking figuratively: perhaps **poetic register** did not catch your attention. My point is that it is ineffective figurative language and thus hard to parse even as figurative language. The speaker does not want women to act like men; she wants woman to act as men should act. The contrast between men **and women** as they are and humans as they should be is completely muddled. So you like the book. It may be a fabulous book, but this passage needed editing or re-writing because even as figurative language it does not say what is intended.

Comment: I've not read the book but I feel have with all the extracts that @Peace has posted :P Have you read it?

Comment: No. I read little fiction these days (except for poetry). I was not trying to assess the book, but the quoted passage. I recognized that it ended in figurative language. In a comment now apparently deleted, the OP asked what the figurative language meant, not just **scorn**. I translated what I am virtually certain was the intended sense of it and recognized that, even as figurative language, it did not capture that sense. By quoting Walker, I hoped to convey sympathy with the intended point while explaining in what way it was expressed poorly.